# How to allow more polyline vertices for a ST_GEOMETRY in Oracle/SDE?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I'm receiving an error writing geometry (in ArcObjects) that has a large number of vertices (around 900).  So big, but not ridiculously big.  I would expect this to be no problem and I don't recall this issue in SQL Server or PostGreSQL.  The geometry storage is ST_GEOMETRY.

The error is:
`ORA-24816: Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column`

..and it appears to be related to the number of vertices that the polyline has on it.  Lots of vertices: I get the above-mentioned error.  Less vertices: no problems.

As a test, I generalized the geometry down to two points: success.

I've started to work my way up and gotten up to 120 vertices with success.  Is there a better way to determine that limit?  Is there a way to increase the number of vertices that I can have on a line?  Is there a DBTUNE parameter that manages this?   I've googled the actual ORA error, but I'm uncertain as to how to apply this to an ArcSDE repository.

A couple of notes:

1. I don't own or administer the ArcSDE repository and can't modify it.
2. Breaking the long polyline feature into several smaller ones is not
   an option (*for this project*).
3. Write using `feature.Shape = geometry; feature.Store();`
4. Code executes as expected for most of the features--I have 2 that have high number of points that cause the ORA error.

**Oracle version:**

`Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production

TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production`

Comment: Based on this [answer at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6827414/125400), I would try creating a new featureclass with the same fields as your current featureclass, _but make the shape field the last field_, and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Yes, I created a new featureclass in my schema and I am able to successfully store! Then add a new field at the end and get the error again.  I also tested with sde binary which worked with no problems.

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit disturbing.  Last I checked you can only add fields to the end of the field list and you cannot have two shapefields in a featureclass.  That sure creates some maintenance headaches.  Have you reported this as a bug to Esri?  I'm starting work on a project that uses Oracle, would like to know if there's an easier workaround.

Comment: I just reported it to Esri, but I think this is an Oracle bug? Based on what I'm reading, other software systems are affected this not just Esri.  Maybe Esri has other options for the ST_GEOMETRY data type (I'm pretty sure the ST_GEOMETRY Point BLOB is the issue here).

Comment: I recall an enhance request a long time ago to allow fields to be added at an arbitrary position in a table (not just at the end).  I don't think it was ever implemented.  The priority of the enhance request might be escalated if it is the only workaround for the bug you report.

Comment: Nice. Esri says to use SDO_GEOMETRY until Oracle fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Arcobjects and Oracle, but from the error message it looks like that sde is probably trying to create the shape incorrectly (bind variables) see http://ora-24816.ora-code.com/ You say the storage type is ST_GEOMETRY- does this means that you are trying to send it as WKT? If so, can you not try it as a native SDO_GEOMETRY object? Is this an option in Arcobjects? Maybe posting part of the code would help

Comment: the ST_GEOMETRY is the geometry storage type, you don't change anything on AO side. It's still a `feature.Shape = geometry; feature.Store();`.  I am not working with any WKT. And this works for thousands of other features--just a couple of these big geometries are falling out due to the ORA error.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the geometry to ITopologicalOperator2, set IsKnownSimple to false, then call Simplify.

Comment: That has no affect, still get the error.  Kirk's comment/link pretty much explains it.